# Does anyone know what the word "Some" means here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, slang, phrase-meaning, dialects

Just to context:

I've playing a gang context game and after a funeral the rival gang drives by shooting and then the characters that were at the funeral have the car blown up and then they have to run away on bike, as character A(CJ) returned earlier to the hood given the fact that he been out of hood for 5 years and thus out of any gangbanging, the character B(Sweet) say this phrase to him:

> Takes you back some, huh, CJ? Yeah

Here **Take back** basically means "**something that awaken memories that happened in the past**", so when Character A(Cj) Was on the hood this things used to happen and now it's like old times

•But my doubt is What's the point of this word "**Some**" here?

> Takes you back **some**, huh, CJ? Yeah

is this a slang used in some dialects or what?

I'll post a video just for context

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G4Qp5mleq60

Timestamp: 0:22

Comment: Have you looked up the definition of 'some'? How does e.g. 'a little' not fit this context?

Comment: Back some means back some time, some years.

Answer (score 2):

[As Merriam-Webster notes,](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/some) "some" can be used an adverb meaning "somewhat" or "to some degree or extent"; it can also serve as a mild intensifier. That is the sense being used here.